# R and RStudio crashes running read_parquet() on Mac M1

Tags: r, arm, apache-arrow

As the title states, both R and RStudio crash with a 'fatal error' when I try to run

```
read_parquet('abc.parquet')
```

For reference, `read_parquet()` is a function from the `arrow()` library

Using:
Macbook Pro M1 2020

- Macbook Pro M1 2020
- R version 4.1.0 (I think it is running through rosetta, activity monitor says 'Intel')
- RStudio 1.4.1717
- arrow 4.0.1

R `sessionInfo()`:

```
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] arrow_4.0.1         data.table_1.14.0   dplyr_1.0.7         bsts_0.9.6          xts_0.12.1         
 [6] zoo_1.8-9           BoomSpikeSlab_1.2.4 Boom_0.9.7          MASS_7.3-54         reshape2_1.4.4     
[11] DescTools_0.99.42   lubridate_1.7.10   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        compiler_4.1.0    pillar_1.6.1      plyr_1.8.6        class_7.3-19      tools_4.1.0      
 [7] bit_4.0.4         boot_1.3-28       tibble_3.1.2      lifecycle_1.0.0   rootSolve_1.8.2.1 lattice_0.20-44  
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.11      Matrix_1.3-3      DBI_1.1.1         rstudioapi_0.13   mvtnorm_1.1-2    
[19] expm_0.999-6      xfun_0.24         e1071_1.7-7       stringr_1.4.0     generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.8      
[25] bit64_4.0.5       tidyselect_1.1.1  gld_2.6.2         grid_4.1.0        glue_1.4.2        R6_2.5.0         
[31] fansi_0.5.0       lmom_2.8          purrr_0.3.4       magrittr_2.0.1    ellipsis_0.3.2    assertthat_0.2.1 
[37] Exact_2.1         utf8_1.2.1        tinytex_0.32      stringi_1.6.2     proxy_0.4-26      crayon_1.4.1
```

Here is a parquet file (one of many) which I am failing to import:

[file.parquet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wnn4zvtvfqad5e/40_loanFrame.parquet?dl=0)

Comment: What version of {arrow}, installed from where? Can you attach a parquet file that crashes? Are you running a native R build or using Rosetta (attaching sessionInfo() would tell us this)? I run on a M1 and haven't personally experienced this, but there are some know issues about binary packages under emulation (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-11217 for example).

Comment: Thanks @NealRichardson I have edited and responded to your questions

Comment: Yeah, the issue is related to the fact that you're running R under emulation instead of native. You should install the arm64 version of R (it should be faster and use less battery too).

Comment: If for some reason you need to run under emulation, you can try installing {arrow} from source (`install.packages("arrow", type = "source")`); I believe `arrow::install_arrow()` will detect that you're running under Rosetta and do the right thing as well.